# Почему не видит зависимость в Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Такая ситуация, есть репозиторий с проектом, с этим проектом работает разработчик и все работает хорошо.

Но теперь мне нужно сделать клон проекта и выполнить в нем новую фичу. После того как я клонировал проект и открыл его я получил вот такую ошибку

```
Error:Could not find com.velocee:veloceeSDK:2.1.6.
Required by:
project :app
searchInBuildFiles
```

я проверил все зависимости все один к одному с другим разработчиком, но у него проект работает у меня нет

Что я делаю не так?

Как это проверить?

Вот так добавлен репозиторий

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/velocee-maven"
}
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
  }
}
```

Как подключаю зависимость в проект

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.velocee:veloceeSDK:2.1.6'
compile 'com.velocee:audioplayer:2.1.6'
}
```

**Правка**

Так же я заметил, что когда открываю `Android Monitor` то там есть такое сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если нажимаю то конфигурация проекта действительно пустая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не уверен или это может действительно влиять на то, что не видит зависимость

Comment: У тебя добавлен в репозитории `url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/velocee-maven` ? https://github.com/Velocee/vlc-android-sdk2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Как подключается эта зависимость в проект?

Comment: @GVArt да у меня есть такая строчка, для наглядности я добавил в вопрос кусок градл файла. Также я все проверил еще раз согласно документации, все в порядке, не могу понять почему он не видит его

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov добавил в вопрос как подключаю ее в проект, очень странно, что на одном компе работает на друго все то же самое и не работает. Не хочет находить репозиторий

Comment: @GVArt Добавил еще в ворос дополнение

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov Добавил еще в ворос дополнение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что разработчики больше не поддерживают эту библиотеку. 
Как вариант, воспользоваться пунктом ["2. Zip Download Project Integration"](https://github.com/Velocee/vlc-android-sdk2/blob/master/README.md)

У вашего коллеги не возникает со сборкой проблем, так как у него эта библиотека закеширована и не требуется повторная загрузка.

Comment: Да я попробовал включить эти 2 файла `.aar` расширение, но все равно не работает. Я так же указал эти строчки  `compile (name:'veloceeSDK', ext:'aar')
    compile (name:'veloceeSDK_Audioplayer', ext:'aar')` . Есть еще идеи?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko А убрали 
compile 'com.velocee:veloceeSDK:2.1.6'
compile 'com.velocee:audioplayer:2.1.6'

? Их тогда нужно убрать